# PHP POST data assign to two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, post

I have a add-to-cart form to $_POST all data, and needed to store into a two dimensional array and assign to a session:

for example **print_r($_POST)** is:

```
Array("prod"=>"ZIU%3D","price"=>"68.00","alt-variation-1"=>"Red","alt-variation-2"=>"L","qty"=>"1")
```

to loop each $_POST:

```
foreach($_POST as $field => $value){
    $f[] = $field;
    $v[] = $value;
}
```

I looking for a way to assign above $f and $v into an array such as:

```
$new_product = array(array($f => $v));
```

and store in a session like:

```
$_SESSION['products'] = $new_product;
```

or any alternate way instead?

Comment: Please show us the result of `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Your loop can be reduced to `$f = array_keys($_POST); $v = array_values($_POST);`. Though in the next step you seem to want to re-combine that into a key-value array... Which looks to me like you can skip that entire dance and do a straight `$_SESSION['products'][] = $_POST`...!?

Comment: Secondarily, is that JSON you're receiving, or why does it look like it?

Comment: @deceze, that is no JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['products'][] = $_POST;` would append the entire post array to the session products array, but you need to validate the data posted by the user.

A better way would be:

```
$data = $_POST;
// sanitise and validate $data here
$_SESSION['products'][] = $data;
```

An example for @HamzaZafeer:

```
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $product){
  echo $product['price'];
}
```

Comment: I will try it tomorrow in work place because the script is not with me now, will update you again. Thanks ya.

Comment: @rybo111 let there is a price in array but then how i can get price from this `$_SESSION['products'][]`

Comment: @HamzaZafeer that would be done in a loop of the products array.  See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

you can encode your array to `JSON` and store it in a `session` with:

```
$myJson = json_encode($_POST);
$_SESSION['myJson'] = serialize($myJson);
```

Comment: `serialize`d JSON in a session?! Why on earth...!?

Comment: Because `JSON` is represented by a string, serializing would be overkill

Comment: ...also, sessions can store arrays and even objects just fine. Storing it *double serialized* will just require you to *double unserialize* the value any time you want to do something with it...